# is "content://" in the Uri of Content Provider in Android replaceable ?

Tags: java, android, android-contentprovider

In our platform, we use a certain format from paths. In the Android App, it receives those paths to load some data or do something.

I want to do all the data handling using content provider, I want to give the path and get data. A simple transaction.

When I read into content providers, the documentation and all the tutorials out there always use "content://" at the beginning. However, I want to use our own start of the path which is usually "is-://". Can something like this work?

Answer (score 1):

no, this is how the system categorize the uri as content provider.
its like relacing file:// with something else.

Answer (score 0):

After referring to [Developer.google](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-basics.html) site

> A content URI is a URI that identifies data in a provider. Content URIs include the symbolic name of the entire provider (its authority) and a name that points to a table (a path). When you call a client method to access a table in a provider, the content URI for the table is one of the arguments.

From this I believe you can't set it on your own as it includes the symbol name.

Also why do you want to change it?

Comment: Just to standardise the paths across all the applications on the platform. The thing in the text you highlighted have its authority between brackets. Does it mean content:// itself or the content provider authority?

Comment: This is just a main phrase of the complete details. For complete detail you can click Developer.google and read thoroughly. You will get the answer that you can't.

Comment: Ok I will check it again. Thanks